# How do I get Sphinx to generate 'contents.rst'?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

The Sphinx templates I use (for example [`sphninxdoc`](http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html#builtin-themes) or [`sphinx13`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/1b7f2df1f87d/doc/_themes/sphinx13/?at=default)) have a link to a **'contents.rst'** file; however, though this file is [documented as "special"](http://www.python.org/doc//current/documenting/markup.html#table-of-contents-markup), I don't see a way to generate it.

Is there a way to get Sphinx to generate **'contents.rst'** automatically, or do I need to generate it manually?

Answer (score 6):

When I came to this page, I needed to fix the [`.readthedocs.yml`](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config-file/v1.html). My sphinx configuration path was missing the "source" part:

```
# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/source/conf.py
```

Within the config, I have

```
# The master toctree document.
master_doc = 'index'
```

Answer (score 3):

The "special" **contents.rst** file that is mentioned in the question is not generated automatically. It is written like any other reST file and is stored in the Python repository: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/contents.rst.

The Python documentation main page at http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/index.html has a [Complete Table of Contents](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/contents.html) link that points to **contents.html**, which is built from contents.rst.

The source for the [Sphinx documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org) includes a similar contents.rst: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/doc/contents.rst.

Comment: There might have been some confusion related to the fact that the default value of `master_doc` was "contents" before Sphinx 2.0. https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-master_doc.